# Navigation of vim autoload functions without ctags

Tags: vim

Is there any vim command or plugin which can jump from a reference of a function to its definition in a script file which is in one of the "autoload" directories except using ctags?

For example, put the cursor above "call xyz#abc#foo()" and enter such command will open file ".../autoload/xyz/abc.vim" and set the cursor position at "function xyz#abc#foo()"

I do not bother with generating tags file every time a new plugin is insalled.

Comment: This feature may be useful to vim plugin developers who refer to multiple autoload script files.

Because the parent directories of "autoload" are listed in 'runtimepath' option and the further sub-directories can be inferred from the function name, it is not hard to locate the position of an autoload function. 

I wonder if somebody has already implemented such feature and uploaded the plugin somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

*(Sorry for the very late answer)*

I use tags to navigate my autoloaded functions.

But I also have an old `:SearchInRuntime sp autoload/xyz/abc.vim` command that'll split open the autoload file we're looking for, if not already open.

But it shouldn't be to hard to implement the feature. Once you have the function name obtained with `expand('<cword>')` or whatever, you could

- build the plugin name: `let plgname = 'autoload/'.substitute(matchstr(fnname, '.*\ze#'), '#', '/', 'g').'.vim'`
- search for it: `let matches = globpath('&rtp', plgname, 1, 1)`
- check you have only one match, ...
- open the file: `exe 'sp '.matches[0]` -- more [subtitle approaches](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/buffer.vim#L101) may be required to avoid to open it several times.
- and then search the function definition: `call search('^\s*fun\%[ction]:\=\s\+'.fnname', ....)`